# Foreign Key References in SQL doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create sets of players and teams. Each player belongs to a team. I reference a 'team' attribute to an attribute 'teamID' in the teams table. But I keep getting error: "Please check for a foreign key constraint on table players for parent table teams"

```
CREATE TABLE players (
  playerid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  name  text,
  position text,
  skill text,
  team integer,
  FOREIGN KEY(team) REFERENCES teams(teamID)

);

CREATE TABLE teams (
  teamID     INTEGER primary key, 
  name   text unique, 
  city text,
  coach text
  /*captain text*/

);

INSERT INTO players VALUES (1, "Tom Chapin", "Quorter Back", "Advanced SKill", 1);
INSERT INTO players VALUES (2, "Harry Chapin", "LineBacker", "Begginer", 2);

/* Tom's songs */
INSERT INTO teams VALUES (1, "Chicago Bears", "Chicago", "Coach Jack");
INSERT INTO teams VALUES (2, "Detroit Bulls", "Detroit", "Coach Bob");
/* Harry's songs */
INSERT INTO teams VALUES (3, "NY Snakes", "New York", "Coach Phil");


SELECT * from players;
SELECT * FROM teams;
```

Comment: Mysql or postgresql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create table team before create table player.

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
  teamID     INTEGER primary key, 
  name   varchar(255) unique, 
  city text,
  coach text
)

CREATE TABLE players (
  playerid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  name  varchar(255),
  position text,
  skill text,
  team integer,
  FOREIGN KEY(team) REFERENCES teams(teamID)

);


/* Tom's songs */
INSERT INTO teams VALUES (1, "Chicago Bears", "Chicago", "Coach Jack");
INSERT INTO teams VALUES (2, "Detroit Bulls", "Detroit", "Coach Bob");
/* Harry's songs */
INSERT INTO teams VALUES (3, "NY Snakes", "New York", "Coach Phil");

INSERT INTO players VALUES (1, "Tom Chapin", "Quorter Back", "Advanced SKill", 1);
INSERT INTO players VALUES (2, "Harry Chapin", "LineBacker", "Begginer", 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The row in the referenced table needs to exist *before* a row can be inserted.

You are attempting to insert rows into `players`.  But these are referencing teams.

You need to insert the `teams` records first.